# How to run Node Js application on apache server

Tags: node.js, apache, web-deployment

So the problem is i'm running spring boot project on a linux server. So, on that server
the URL of that project is - **https://project-name**

Now i want to install a Node js project on same server
Node js project link- https://github.com/WPS/domain-story-modeler

The node js project is running on 9013 port
So, if someone hit the **https://project-name/domain-story-modeler** it should redirect to node js project
for that i have used reverse proxy of apache which will redirect to node js project

```
ProxyPass        /domain-story-modeler http://localhost:9013

ProxyPassReverse /domain-story-modeler http://localhost:9013
```

And i run the node js project using pm2
`pm2 start "npm run dev" --name domain-story-modeler` and it run

The issue im facing currently is if i hit the **https://project-name/domain-story-modeler** it is accessing the node js project but only able to show index.html file and unable to access rest of the file like css , js, images and all
So, i want to know why is these happening.

If you want more details about issue i can provide

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys ,
But i found the solution
The issue was the url i was hitting is **https://project-name/domain-story-modeler**
and image tag in index.html file has path from logo folder

when i updated it with the project folder everything start working